# To derive a table out of an existing one

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

```
Table: 
A | B | C  | D
1   q   123  23 
2   w   22   32
3   e   23   21

New table: 
A | B | C  | D
1   q   123  C
1   q   23   D
2   w   22   C
2   w   32   D
3   e   23   C
3   e   21   D
```

I want to derive a new table/view from an existing table, where I want the records in the first table to be split by a column name.

C and D are months in the original table. In the new table I want the months to be as records.

The records in the original table for the months (123,23 for 1) should match the months column and be put into another column in the new table.

Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: Do a UNION ALL.

Comment: Can you show me how, I did not understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `UNION ALL`, with one select for the c's and one select for the d's.

```
select a, b, c, 'c' from tablename
union all
select a, b, d, 'd' from tablename
```